# Inserting a space between \n and a string variable in php

Tags: php, newline, whitespace

This is apparently a bigger task than I expected. I would like to have a white space inserted between a line break and a string in php code.

```
$space = " ";
$chainOfwords = $chainOfwords."\n".$space.$word;
```

I have assigned &nbsp ; to $space so far too. Also this did not do the trick.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What did it do if it did not work? I suspect that it worked, but you could not tell.

Comment: What does your code produce? What is it supposed to produce? Do you mean that the isn't showing up on a webpage when you run your PHP?

Comment: If I assign "&nbsp ;" to $space than a space is not inserted, but the exactly &nbsp is visible. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why "&nbsp ;" did not appear as a whitespace but as it is written, is because of a filter I was using in the twig template(Symfony2 framework). 
Instead of this

```
<label>{{descriptiontext|nl2br}}<label/>
```

I had to do this

```
<label>{{descriptiontext|raw}}<label/>
```

And then my php code above worked. I should have mentioned that I was using Symfony2 framework, but I did not know then that it had that impact. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works ... view browser source to see. The reason that you are not seeing it is that the browser ignores multiple occurances of whitespace.

Try

```
$space = "&nbsp;";
```

for a space you can see in the browser.

Also your \n may not be visible to you ... if that is the case replace it with a `<br/>`